# How can I get the webdriverxx (c++) browser to work?

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, libcurl

I am using this [webdriverxx](https://github.com/sekogan/webdriverxx) for c++.

---

**1. Problem**

Everything works fine (and worked fine) but I can't use the browser anymore.

```
WebDriver dr = Start(Chrome().SetProxy(HttpProxy(proxy)));
```

So I get this error: "WEBDRIVERXX_FUNCTION_CONTEXT_END()" | "
untreated exception". I think it has something to do with the selenium server and the chromedriver. But I don't understand how the selenium server works and all that.

---

**2. Problem:**

The Proxy thing isn't working for me. I tested the proxies and they are good but they don't get "activated". (This nerver worked.)

---

(Sorry for my bad english...)